# Angular: getting independent data for each item in ngFor loop

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm new to Angular2+ and testing out some UI. To do so I want to place a random number inside a set of containers that are added via an `ngFor`:

```
<div class="table-row" *ngFor="let row of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]">
  <div class="table-cell">{{fakeData()}}</div>
  <div class="table-cell">{{fakeData()}}</div>
  <div class="table-cell">{{fakeData()}}</div>
  <div class="table-cell">{{fakeData()}}</div>
</div>
```

This basically produces 6 rows with 4 columns that should hold a temp number.

When I used `fakeData = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(300));` it produced the same number for each cell. When I made this a function (like above) the numbers are different in each cell but they keep changing. Obviously getting data on a per row/cell will come in handy when I start pulling and placing real data in here.

Comment: is fakeData a function or a variable? because according to your table it's function but according t your fakeData code is a variable.

Comment: I just worded it odd. I used a variable first and got the same number for each (which I understand why) the second was with a function.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function directly from the template, it is called each frame.
So your function fakeData() is doing its job by giving you new random numbers every frame

I don't know why you want a random number for each cell but one thing usefull is the index of *ngFor

```
<div class="table-row" *ngFor="let row of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]; index as i">
  <div class="table-cell">{{100*i + 1}}</div>
  <div class="table-cell">{{100*i + 2}}</div>
  <div class="table-cell">{{100*i + 3}}</div>
  <div class="table-cell">{{100*i + 4}}</div>
</div>
```

That will give you something like this (below). Because i (index) is the index of the loop you are currently running

1 2 3 4
101 102 103 104
201 202 203 204 , etc

Comment: That makes sense. So, how do I go about placing a random number in each cell with in the `ngFor` while also avoiding this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an array of objects ? Your data will probably end up being one.

```
myData = [
          {key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2', key3: 'val3', key4: 'val4'},
          {key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2', key3: 'val3', key4: 'val4'}
         ];

<div class="table-row" *ngFor="let obj of myData">
  <div class="table-cell">{{obj.key1}}</div>
  <div class="table-cell">{{obj.key2}}</div>
  <div class="table-cell">{{obj.key3}}</div>
  <div class="table-cell">{{obj.key4}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought about doing that way but the eventually hardcoded "test" data will be pretty big so I was trying to reduce work so I can generate 50 rows with 100 cells each using an ngFor without having to create an object to fill it.

Comment: You could build the object in the component, wrap your function in an observable and use the async pipe to get the results to display once all the values have been generated.

Comment: @Stanislasdrg generating a bunch of numbers isn't an asynchronous operation. There's no reason to use the async pipe or observables.

Comment: @DavidWalschots True. It was just a suggestion, considering the data would probably end up being pulled from an API.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that angular continously updates the page when it recogniozes change.

To solve your issue you can fill your data to an array(maybe into two-dimentional array which depends on your need) in ts, then call ngFor in html.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work the following way:

In your html:

```
   <div class="table-row" *ngFor="let row of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]">
        <div class="table-cell">{{fakeData()}}</div>
      </div>
```

In your .ts file:

```
 fakeData() {
    return  Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(300));
  }
```

Comment: I did that way and it changes the number over and over again.

Comment: @dcp3450 I guess I missed understood your question, so you want to have the random number to be stored some how and after that random number being generated have always that number?

Comment: Correct. This is all test data though, just so I can get my UI in place. I need it random so the width change and I don't assume anything in my UI.

Comment: @dcp3450 were you able to do this? I'm trying to do exactly the same thing